# express response hangs when i use a middleware to stop multer upload of large files

Tags: node.js, express, upload, response, multer

im facing a porblem for a middleware to stop large files uploads before the multer function run  , im testing with 2 gb file

the route function :

router.post('/upload_files' ,  sec_check ,  upload_multer , async(req , res   )=>{}

the middleware :

```
function sec_check(req , res   , next){


    console.log("[SEC CHECK ran  ! ]")

    if(req.headers['content-length'] > 600000000){
        console.log("this message is displayed on console meaning it entered the logic")
        

        return res.send("this res never sent and hangs and sometimes shown after 40 seconds why it doesnt end immediately does the form multipart affect it ! ")


    }else{

        console.log("[SEC CHECK cleared    u can continue the upload]")
        next()
    }


}
```

---

what i have  tried :
1- remove the bodyParser completely still same error
2- i did req.destroy() but that doesn't show the res ! it kill the connection , why express response freeze and hang like that .